# Initialising empty arrays of dictionaries in Swift

Tags: arrays, dictionary, swift

I'm trying to wrap my head around initialising empty arrays in Swift.

For an array of strings it's pretty straight forward :

```
var myStringArray: String[] = []
myStringArray += "a"
myStringArray += "b"

-> ["a", "b"]
```

and for integers

```
var myIntArray: Int[] = []
myIntArray += 1
myIntArray += 2

-> [1, 2]
```

it also works for other types of object such as NSImage objects :

```
let path = "/Library/Application Support/Apple/iChat Icons/Flags/"
let image1 = NSImage(byReferencingFile: path + "Brazil.png")
let image2 = NSImage(byReferencingFile: path + "Chile.png")

var myImageArray: NSImage[] = []
myImageArray += image1
myImageArray += image2

-> [<NSImage 0x7fe371c199f0 ...>, <NSImage 0x7fe371f39ea0 ...>]
```

However I can't work out the syntax to initialise an empty array of Dictionaries.

I know you can have an array of Dictionaries because initialising with an initial value works :

```
let myDict1 = ["someKey":"someValue"]
let myDict2 = ["anotherKey":"anotherValue"]

var myDictArray = [myDict1]
myDictArray += myDict2

-> [["someKey": "someValue"], ["anotherKey": "anotherValue"]]
```

This however (which you'd expect the syntax to be) fails :

```
var myNewDictArray: Dictionary[] = []
```

with the error `Cannot convert the expression's type 'Dictionary[]' to type 'Hashable'`

So the question is what is the correct way to initialise a empty array of Dictionary Items and why doesn't this syntax `var myNewDictArray: Dictionary[] = []` work?

Answer (score 228, accepted):

You need to give types to the dictionaries:

```
var myNewDictArray: [Dictionary<String, Int>] = []
```

or

```
var myNewDictArray = [Dictionary<String, Int>]()
```

**Edit**: You can also use the shorter syntax:

```
var myNewDictArray: [[String:Int]] = []
```

or

```
var myNewDictArray = [[String:Int]]()
```

Answer (score 9):

This will create an empty, immutable dictionary:

`let dictionary = [ : ]`

And if you want a mutable one:

`var dictionary = [ : ]`

Both of these dictionaries default to `Dictionary<String?, AnyObject?>`.

Comment: Your example is not about the immutability of the dictionaries, but the immutability of the variables.

Answer (score 6):

The reason this isn't working:

```
var myNewDictArray: Dictionary[] = []
```

is that you need to provide types for the keys and values of a dictionary when you define it. Each of these lines will create you an empty array of dictionaries with string keys and string values:

```
var dictArray1: Dictionary<String, String>[] = Dictionary<String, String>[]()
var dictArray2: Dictionary<String, String>[] = []
var dictArray3 = Dictionary<String, String>[]()
```

Comment: Yes, this works. Any idea why there are two ways of doing it?

Comment: Swift uses *type inference* at compile-time, so when declaring a variable you can either specify the type (like `dictArray2` does) or immediately assign it something that the compiler can figure out (like `dictArray3` does). The first line is more verbose than necessary, but the compiler doesn't mind that.

Comment: i had to change on Swift 2     **var productImageArray: [Dictionary<String, String>] = [ ]**

Answer (score 0):

You can no longer use element concatenation.

```
class Image {}
Image i1
Image i2

var x = [Image]()

x += i1 // will not work (adding an element is ambiguous)
x += [i1] // this will work (concatenate an array to an array with the same elements)

x += [i1, i2] // also good
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourArrayname = [String]() // String or anyOther according to need
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this if u want to use swift 2.3!

```
let path = "/Library/Application Support/Apple/iChat Icons/Flags/"
let image1 = UIImage(contentsOfFile: readPath + "Brazil.png")
let image2 = UIImage(contentsOfFile: readPath + "Chile.png")

var myImageArray = [UIImage]()
myImageArray.append(image1)
myImageArray.append(image2)
```

Comment: Please add an explanation, what you code actually does. And why it should fix op's problem.