# Pictures shifting randomly in UITableView after being retrieved from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-storage

As my title states, the pictures in my tableView shift around and are not being displayed on the correct posts when scrolling through the table view. After I stop scrolling they seem to be back into place.

I've been trying to make a sense out of the following articles:

[new Firebase retrieve data and put on the tableview swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37895171/new-firebase-retrieve-data-and-put-on-the-tableview-swift)

[retrieve image from Firebase storage to show on tableview swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37913871/retrieve-image-from-firebase-storage-to-show-on-tableview-swift)

[swift Firebase sort posts in tableview by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37103192/swift-firebase-sort-posts-in-tableview-by-date/37126528#37126528)

But I cannot figure out how to make the pictures to display better.
Here's what I have:

```
    import UIKit
    import FirebaseAuth
    import FirebaseDatabase
    import FirebaseStorage

    class MainFeedTableViewController: UITableViewController {

        var posts = [Post]()

        let alert = AlertsViewController()

        var databaseRef: FIRDatabaseReference! {
            return FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        }

        var storageRef: FIRStorage! {
            return FIRStorage.storage()
        }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fetchPosts()

    }

    // populates the tableView with posts content in real time
    private func fetchPosts(){

        let postRefs = databaseRef.child("posts")

        postRefs.observe(.value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
            var newPost = [Post]()

            for post in snapshot.children{
                let postObject = Post(snapshot: post as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                newPost.insert(postObject, at: 0)
            }

            self.posts = newPost
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let postsAtIndexPath = posts[indexPath.row]

        if postsAtIndexPath.postWithImage == true {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postWithImage", for: indexPath) as! PostWithImageTableViewCell

            let postUser = postsAtIndexPath.uid

            let userRef = databaseRef.child("users/\(postUser!)")

            userRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                let user = User(snapshot: snapshot)

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    cell.userRealNameLabel.text = user.name
                    cell.usernameLabel.text = "@" + user.username
                    cell.postTextView.text = postsAtIndexPath.postText
                    cell.timeStampLabel.text = postsAtIndexPath.date
                })

                self.storageRef.reference(forURL: user.photoURL).data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in

                    if error == nil{

                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                            if let data = data{
                                cell.userProfilePicture.image = UIImage(data: data)
                            }
                        })

                    }
                    else{

                        print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    }
                })

                self.storageRef.reference(forURL: postsAtIndexPath.postPictureURL).data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in

                    if error == nil{

                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                            if let data = data{
                                cell.postImage.image = UIImage(data: data)

                            }
                        })

                    }
                    else{
                        self.alert.displayAlert(alertTitle: "Error", alertMessage: error!.localizedDescription, fromController: self)
                    }
                })

            }) { (error) in
                self.alert.displayAlert(alertTitle: "Error", alertMessage: error.localizedDescription, fromController: self)
            }

            return cell
        }
        else{

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postWithText", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell

            let postUser = postsAtIndexPath.uid

            let userRef = databaseRef.child("users/\(postUser!)")

            userRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                let user = User(snapshot: snapshot)

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    cell.userRealNameLabel.text = user.name
                    cell.usernameLabel.text = "@" + user.username
                    cell.postTextView.text = postsAtIndexPath.postText
                    cell.timestampLabel.text = postsAtIndexPath.date

                })

                self.storageRef.reference(forURL: user.photoURL).data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in

                    if error == nil{

                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                            if let data = data{
                                cell.userProfilePicture.image = UIImage(data: data)
                            }
                        })

                    }
                    else{

                        print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    }
                })

            }) { (error) in
                self.alert.displayAlert(alertTitle: "Error", alertMessage: error.localizedDescription, fromController: self)
            }

            return cell
        }

    }

}
```

The reason I'm having a hard time, it's because I want the user's username, name, and profile picture to change everywhere and in real time when they edit their info. That's why I'm retrieving the user info based on the post's user uid.

What's a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to override the `prepareForReuse` function in `PostWithImageTableViewCell`.

**EXAMPLE**

```
 override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.userProfilePicture.image = nil
        //reset the rest of the values on your `UITableViewCell` subclass
 }
```

**EDIT**

Since the reuse issue has been resolved, i would like to recommend the following caching framework, [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher), for more convenient image display experience.

Kingfisher has a great extension on `UIImageView`, what will take care of the caching for your.

Here how you would use it:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://domain.com/image.jpg")!
imageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
```

You only set to the URL, what will uniquely identify the image resource, and downloads only once. Here is a [cheat sheet](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Cheat-Sheet), how to use it.

Comment: okay it works, but now every time I scroll it looks like the pictures are loading, so they appear as I scroll. Is there a way to keep the cells loaded with the pictures that are already showing without having to reload them? idk if that makes sense

Comment: of course. start the downloading of the images independently from showing the cells. or introduce some sort of cashing to store the images, and only download them once.

Comment: do you have an example of that by any chance?

Comment: are you using cocoapods in your project?

Comment: Yes sir. It's required for Firebase.

Comment: Thank you. Will check it out!

Comment: have fun and keep building great software!

Comment: Another question, how will Kingfisher know to what post assign each picture?

Comment: the url u are accessing the image from is unique, u set it up once, and if an image has been downloaded already from that url, it will not download it once more, just read it from the cash.

Comment: must be doing something not right. post it as another question, i take a look tomorrow.